# Group regex is missing last match

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

as given in sample code **fstr** need match all occurence of **regEx_C** and need to replace with some dynamic value. and make sure each match should have unique value.

in this sample *fstr.match(regEX_C)* matches 4 match and i need to replace with 1 dynamic value for each.

---

1. var_Viablecells_C = X
2. var_IVCC_C = Y
3. var_Viablecells_C = Z
4. var_IVCC_C = Z1

   the value assigned should not match with anyone.

---

```js
var fstr = '(Math.log(var_Viablecells_C-var_Viablecells_P)/(2-1)+ var_IVCC_C + var_Viablecells_C / var_IVCC_C)';
var regEx_C = /var_(\w+)_C/ig;
var c_val = 5.5;

function putExpValForRegExMatch(fstr, regEx, val) {
  var all_match = fstr.match(regEx);
  if (null == all_match) return fstr;
  console.log(all_match);
  for (var i = 0; i < all_match.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(fstr);
    var current_match = regEx.exec(fstr);
    if (current_match == null) return fstr;
    console.log(current_match);
    fstr = replaceRange(fstr, current_match.index, current_match.index + current_match[0].length - 1, '');
    fstr = replaceAt(fstr, current_match.index, val);
    console.log(fstr);
  }
  return fstr;
}

function replaceAt(string, index, replace) {
  return string.substring(0, index) + replace + string.substring(index + 1);
}

function replaceRange(s, start, end, substitute) {
  return s.substring(0, start) + substitute + s.substring(end);
}

console.log(putExpValForRegExMatch(fstr, regEx_C, c_val));
```

Comment: I feel all you need is to replace all that long method body with `return fstr.replace(/var_\w+_C/g, val);`, please check https://jsfiddle.net/ymw4ccaz/

Comment: You say you *need to apply different val for each match* - please explain the requirements in the question body.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew now can you try?

Comment: It is too vague. Please consider this approach at asking: 1) "I have `'(Math.log(var_Viablecells_C-var_Viablecells_P)/(2-1)+ var_IVCC_C + var_Viablecells_C / var_IVCC_C)'` string", 2) "I need to get `"....."` because I want to replace `var_Viablecells_C` with `5.5`" (??? correct???), 3) "I get `(Math.log(5.5-var_Viablecells_P)/(2-1)+ 5.5 + var_Viablecells_C / 5.5)` where the  `var_Viablecells_C / 5.5` part is incorrect as I expect it to be `...`". Sounds good? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Mukesh, why is the replacement like that? 1) Because the first match should be replaced with `X, the second with `Y`, the third with `Z`, the fourth with `Z1`... but what about the next, if any? 2) Or because the first match with `Viablecells` in Group 1 should be replaced with `X`, then the second must be replaced with `Z`, and the first match with `IVCC` in Group 1 must be replaced with `Y`, the second with `Z1` (what about third, fourth and more occurrences?)

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/jws49yx2/

Comment: thats not really X,Y and Z, its random decimal value which will be fill at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `string.prototype.replace()`

```
var fstr = '(Math.log(var_Viablecells_C-var_Viablecells_P)/(2-1)+ var_IVCC_C + var_Viablecells_C / var_IVCC_C)';
var regEx_C = /var_(\w+)_C/ig;
var c_val = 5.5;

output = fstr.replace(regEx_C,c_val)
```

Comment: You do not need the capturing group with this approach.

Comment: i know that but need to apply different val for each match